# How to Show Error Page On Accessing The Views Folder in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I want to redirect the user to  an error page when someone  tries to access the Views Folder of the website.I have implemented the same scenarios for bin and other folders only the views folder is not getting identified.

Kindly help me to figure out this.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
    string curruntpath = Request.Path.ToLower(); 
    string[] arrInvalidPaths = new string[] { 
                         "/reports", 
                         "/reports/", 
                         "/resources", 
                         "/resources/", 
                         "/scripts", 
                         "/scripts/", 
                         "/service references", 
                         "/service references/", 
                         "/usercontrols", 
                         "/usercontrols/", 
                         "/views", 
                         "/views/" //not handled };  

        HttpContext obj = HttpContext.Current;
        string finalURL = curruntpath;

        if (Array.IndexOf(arrInvalidPaths, curruntpath) > -1)
        {
            obj.RewritePath("~/Error/Index");
        }
```

Comment: how do you do it for the other folders? some code?

Comment: Do you have a route that might pick up `/Views`?

Comment: protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string curruntpath = Request.Path.ToLower();
            string[] arrInvalidPaths = new string[] 
            {        
                "/reports",             "/reports/",
                "/resources",           "/resources/",
                "/scripts",             "/scripts/",
                "/service references",  "/service references/",
                "/usercontrols",        "/usercontrols/",
                "/views",               "/views/"               //not handled
            };

Comment: i dont have route to map witht he views :(

Comment: can you show what is comming next? what are you doning with the arrInvalidPaths?

Comment: and how is the url of your view?

Comment: how is your url to the view?

Answer (score 0):

inside the controller you can show another page if you want

```
class myController : Controller
{
     ActionResult Index()
     {
         If(someCheck)
         {
              return RedirectToAction("ErrorView");
         }

         return View();
     }

     ActionResult ErrorView()
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

Comment: the main problem is that the request for the views folder in not  getting tracked down on the controller i have written code  to verify the request in the begin_request in global.asax.

Comment: i have edited  the and given the full code  for the same.